# React.AspNet 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

Im trying to install React.AspNet Package to my .NET Core MVC app and this gives me error

> React.AspNet 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0

But here https://reactjs.net/2016/10/3.0.0-release.html I have read that is supports .Net Core , so whats wrong?

Comment: It works for me. Try to add package into project.json manullay. May be this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading newest .NET Core 1.0.1 from here https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows everything looks to work fine.